# Is it possible to query an AppSync GraphQL type by timestamps?

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I want to query all instances of a model by the most recently created.

Reading the official docs, they suggest a way of querying by the default timestamps (`updatedAt`/`createdAt`) but *only* when also querying by another key. So I know I could query a hypothetical `User` model by `name` and `createdAt`, but I can't query all instances of `User` by `createdAt`.

Is there an established way of doing this?

I have tried adding a `@key` directive to sort by `updatedAt`, but that results in an error because `updatedAt` is automatically added and not described in my schema. If I then add the timestamps to my schema this creates problems when mutating clients because it expects the timestamps to be added by me, which I obviously don't do because it's automatically added by DynamoDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on the field you want to query. In your AppSync resolver, you need to specify the index you want to use for the query.

Another way would be to run a `scan` operation against your DB (you don't need to specify a key in this case), although that would be way more inefficient than a `GSI`.